# Hover on element where attribute is set

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can I put a hover style on an element which is not disabled? I tried the following, but there was no hover effect.

```
input.btn[disabled='false']:hover
```

Comment: Is that sample something you tried? What happened?

Comment: Yes, have tried it.. No hover effect at all on any `input.btn` elms

Comment: I tested it in Chrome and it worked ok. It is important to note that IE7 and IE8 support attribute selectors only if a !DOCTYPE is specified and attribute selection isn't supported in IE6 and lower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using the `enabled` selector?

```
<script>$("input:enabled").val("this is it");</script>
```

Here is a link to the docs
http://api.jquery.com/enabled-selector/

Comment: btw. It was not a jquery question :P

Comment: For a css only solution I would add a class to inputs that are enabled and then target them with the css that way.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should rather use

```
input:not([disabled="disabled"]):hover {
    border: 1px solid red;
}​
```

But this pseudo-selector won't work in most of the browsers, I think.

See http://jsfiddle.net/xmKbt/5/.

Comment: I need it to be opposite.. have tried to remove the ~ but its the same

Comment: Sorry, just figured out that I got it completely wrong. Just updated it with a solution that should work. However, the browser compatibility is not the best.

Comment: Another option would be to do the 'positive' thing and just manually add a class 'not_disabled' to the button which will make the selector a lot simpler.

Comment: Use `:not([disabled])` instead, and don't forget the `.btn` class.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot **set** a pseudo class according to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CSS) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531207%28VS.85%29.aspx).